# Random suspend after closing lid. Surface Pro 2 - 16.10

Tags: suspend, power-management, 16.10, surface

I am having a constant issue where my Surface Pro 2 is suspending randomly after closing the lid and then reopening for the first time per session.

After reboot the issue goes away until the next time I close the lid and reopen.

I have installed TLP for power management, and I would like to maintain the ability to suspend and wake via the lid.

Thanks in advance

Comment: By "suspending randomly" you mean sometimes it doesn't?

Comment: Sorry, no I mean it will just suspend for no reason while actively using the machine. Closing the lid consistently suspends.